# nivo slider and lightbox conflict jquery

Tags: jquery, lightbox, nivo-slider

Can anybody help me with this jquery function. I know it is a conflict with both, but i dont know what i must change.

It works both allown on the page. But toghter the lightbox doesn´t work.

Lightbox

```
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Nivo slider

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect:'fade',
    slices:10,
    animSpeed:1500,
    pauseTime:10000,
    directionNav:true, //Next & Prev
    directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
    controlNav:true, //1,2,3...
    keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
    pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
    captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
    beforeChange: function(){},
    afterChange: function(){},
    slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(window).load(function() {
  j('#slider').nivoSlider({
```

Answer (score 0):

just to say I had the same problem.

Plugins:

- jQuery Lightbox For Native Galleries
- Nivo Slider for WordPress

I made it work by removing line 32:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

from nivoslider4wp-shop.php located in the \plugins\nivo-slider-for-wordpress\

I hope that helps.