# nivo slider + camera slideshow = conflict?

Tags: wordpress, conflict, nivo-slider

Grateful for your help.

I'm experience a conflict (for lack of a better word) between nivo Slider and Camera slide show. (nivo Slider is native to the wordpress theme we use--and is our main navigational feature on the sites landing page. Camera is of course a plugin and gets inserted via shortcode [camera slideshow="my-slideshow"])

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681198/nivo-slider-and-lightbox-conflict-jquery) seems to have a promising answer. But I'm novice enough to be at a loss as to where to place this script--or if the script is the right solution.

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(window).load(function() {
  j('#slider').nivoSlider({
```

Again, grateful for your help.

Comment: did you try posting this to the wordpress forums?  they are usually very helpful and responsive

Comment: Yep. Thanks. Last night. Nothing helpful from there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check the js console in browser for errors or add a link to your site. 
Possible reason: doubled call for jQuery. You may check in page source for (or similar)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```